# Expandir imagen de fondo por completo en un RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Quiero que una imagen ocupe por completo el fondo de toda la pantalla y para ello utilizo el atributo `background` del `RelativeLayout`principal
El `layout` correspondiente a la `Activity` es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoinicio"
    tools:context="com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo.MainActivity"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Como se aprecia en la siguiente captura queda una linea vertical blanca a la derecha de la pantalla que no logro eliminar. La captura esta realizada en el `preview` de `Android Studio`. Concretamente de un Nexus 5X con una pantalla de `1080x1920: 420 dpi`, pero ocurre lo mismo con los distintos dispositivos que ofrece `Android Studio`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen la guardo en distintas densidades. Estos son lo datos:

- hdpi (564x1001)
- mdpi (376x667)
- xhdpi (752x1334)
- xxhdpi (1128x2001)
- xxxhdpi (1504x2668)

Comment: Mejor opción es poner un ImageView y la imagen allí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problemas estaba en la imagen. Las imágenes las exportaba en distintas densidades en `Sketch`, usando el `plugin` `Sketch Android assets` y al parecer este `plugin` tiene un error. Añade una linea vertical del tamaño de un `pixel` la cual solo se aprecia al seleccionar la imagen.

Adjunto imagen con muchísimo zoom para que se aprecie el error en la exportación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando otro plugin de exportación el problema ha sido resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción sería agregar la imagen dentro de un [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html?hl=es)

y usar la propiedad :

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya lo prove anteriormente. En cierto que la linea parece que a disminuido algo, pero sigue estando.

Comment: podrías compartir la imagen, si probaste en diferentes dispositivos podría asegurar que la imagen es el problema.

Comment: Como no sé que densidad es la que te tengo subir, aquí https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6704838/drawables.zip he comprimidos todas las densidades.